# How to make a void protected method return response in Junits

Tags: junit, mockito

How to mock a void protected Method in a filter using mockito  and make it return some "response"

since it's a void method ,i cannot use doReturn(some value) ,is there a way to set a  response  and make

it return that.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Can you show some example code that you are wanting to test? I think we need some context to understand what you are after.

Comment: How can void return responses?

Comment: I want to test a filter which has a void method

Comment: protecetd void dofilter(request,response,filterchain) .this is the method i'm trying to test in a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you **can't**, the long answer is that even if you could, you *shouldn't*.

The purpose of your test should be to verify the behaviour of your class/method.  What does your filter do? What are the possible paths through the code? It must either return a value, have a side-effect or communicate with another object.  These are the things that you should be testing for.

For example, seeing as this is a filter chain I assume that it's going to apply some logic and either call the next filter or not.  You should mock the next filter in the chain and assert that it's called correctly or not depending on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can return any response from methods that returns void but in case if we want to mock a method that returns void we could use:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(apiService).methodNamethatReturnsVoid(Mockito.anyString();
```